# Uploading App to Play Store Causing Error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-studio-2.3

I am trying to publish an app onto the `Google Play Store`. I signed the app using the `keystore` (`Build -> Generate Signed Apk` in `Android Studio`).

But when I try to publish it in the play store, I am getting the following error.

```
Upload failed
You uploaded an unsigned APK. You need to create a signed APK.
```

I tried several times and even created new keystores and tried from it. There is no difference.

I am using the latest `Android Studio 2.3`

How to fix it ?

Comment: Sure you're uploading the correct file?  Building will generally create an unsigned and a signed apk file.

Comment: Where in your file directory do you take the apk from?

Comment: I have specified the location to generate the APK. 'APK Destination Folder' myself.

Comment: Did you get the solution? @mjm

Comment: @AnshulTyagi I think it is a error by Google. After several retries apparently it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The keystore only generates the key you will use to sign all your apks. I have not used android studio to sign my apks before. You can use the command line, it's pretty straightforward.
Step 1: generate a key using keystore if you don't have one

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

If this ran successfully, you should have `my-release-key.keystore` in your current directory

Step 2: Sign your apk using the jarsigner

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore <path to unsigned apk>.apk alias_name
```

Step 3: You need to optimize the APK using the zip align tool

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign -v 4 <path to unsigned apk>.apk <whatever name>.apk
```

Note: You can replace `~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign` with the path to your zipalign file

Also when trying to sign using Android Studio it should bring a prompt where you have to enter your password to your keystore, if you are not seeing this, it means you have not generated a keystore. You can just use the step 1 above and then try to build using Android Studio again.

Another way is 
Step 1 Go to Build>Generate Signed APK>Next (module selected would be your module , most often called "app")

Step 2 Click on create new

Step 3 Basically, fill in the form with the required details. The confusing bit it is where it asks for a Key Store Path. Click on the icon on the right with the 3 dots ("..."), which will open up a navigator window asking you to navigate and select a .jks file.Navigate to a folder where you want your keystore file saved and then at the File Name box at the bottom of that window, simply enter a name of your liking and the OK button will be clickable now. What is happening is that the window isnt really asking you chose a .jks file but rather it wants you to give it the location and name that you want it to have.

Step 4 Click on Next and then select Release and this should work

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to `zipalign` your signed APK and upload the generated aligned apk to the Play Store.

Run `zipalign –v 4 non-aligned-apk.apk aligned-apk.apk`

`zipalign` is located in `~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/{version}/`